# Current Android Google Spreadsheet API Example for writing

Tags: android

I'm looking for an example of writing a Google Spreadsheet and adding rows to it from Android. All the examples I've found so far are either out of date, only include authentication, or only listing documents/spreadsheets (without including any writes). Do you know of any examples of creating a spreadsheet and adding rows to it?

Comment: would you please share the links you have about the authentication? do you have anything about oAuth2.0 authentication?

Comment: @LorenzoSciuto I think the oAuth2.0 can be done most easily with Google Play Services now; see for e.g., http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html 
And then you can take the token and give it to the code in this example:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20

Answer (score 1):

Here is an api wrapper for Android for the Google spreadsheet api:
git@github.com:ralph240574/spreadsheet-api.git

And a working example:
git@github.com:ralph240574/spreadsheet-api-android-example.git

And here is an app that uses the api:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iubiquity.fc

Comment: I get Maven build errors. so this did not work for me.

Comment: App Link is expired!

Answer (score 1):

The spreadsheets stuff seems to be changing all the time, and it's hard to tell whether or not it's supported and to what degree. But I am currently following up the simplest leads that seem promising. That includes:

1. Authenticating the user with [oAuth2.0 from Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html)
2. Following the latest instructions in the [API v3.0 Documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/)

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at this link:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets

and to this question:

[Android - Google Spreadsheet Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838963/android-google-spreadsheet-api)