# Google Docs / Drive for editing Spreadsheet on Android

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I want to simply use my Google-Account to read in Table Rows from a Google Docs File. The examples provided by Google are over-engineered,

1) Setting up a Play Service
2) Activating Drive SDK
3) Using OAuth
4) Activating Intent
5....

The [Quick-Start](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) Example provided by Google needs a lot of configuration as well. A Google Announcement of "sweat less google-drive" api on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quQyZdhPjxc) is not the reality or maybe i am on the wrong path.

Could someone give me an advice?

It seems that i am not the only one struggling: [Current Android Google Spreadsheet API Example for writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665451/current-android-google-spreadsheet-api-example-for-writing)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive Android API doesn't support reading or editing Google Spreadsheets content, however the Google Sheets API 3.0 has a Java wrapper that you should be able to use on Android. See this link for more info: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Comment: it uses gdata library that has issues w/ android, did you try editing spreadsheet from android with it? Is it OK?