# how to store data from sqlite to google excel sheet

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new in android. I made a 3 columns in **sqlite** and I am storing user input in sqlite

I want when device get Wifi(Internet) it will upload all data to google excel sheet accordingly with column on specific user account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is to convert the sqlite database into csv in first step then in second step is to convert the csv file to xls and it works fine for me, you will need 2 libraries (opencsv-1.7.jar; poi-3.8-20120326.jar)

```
  public class ExportDatabaseCSVTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>

{

private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(DatabaseExampleActivity.this);

 @Override

protected void onPreExecute()

{

    this.dialog.setMessage("Exporting database...");

    this.dialog.show();

}



protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args)

{


    File dbFile=getDatabasePath("database_name");
    //AABDatabaseManager dbhelper = new AABDatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());
    AABDatabaseManager dbhelper = new AABDatabaseManager(DatabaseExampleActivity.this) ;
    System.out.println(dbFile);  // displays the data base path in your logcat 


    File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");        

    if (!exportDir.exists()) 

    {
        exportDir.mkdirs();
    }


    File file = new File(exportDir, "excerDB.csv");


    try

    {

        if (file.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println("File is created!");
            System.out.println("myfile.csv "+file.getAbsolutePath());
          }else{
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
          }

        CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
      //SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor curCSV=db.getdb().rawQuery("select * from " + db.TABLE_NAME,null);

        csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

        while(curCSV.moveToNext())

        {

            String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1),curCSV.getString(2)};

         /*curCSV.getString(3),curCSV.getString(4)};*/

            csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);


        }

        csvWrite.close();
        curCSV.close();
        /*String data="";
        data=readSavedData();
        data= data.replace(",", ";");
        writeData(data);*/

        return true;

    }

    catch(SQLException sqlEx)

    {

        Log.e("MainActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);

        return false;

    }

    catch (IOException e)

    {

        Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);

        return false;

    }

}

protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success)

{

    if (this.dialog.isShowing())

    {

        this.dialog.dismiss();

    }

    if (success)

    {

        Toast.makeText(DatabaseExampleActivity.this, "Export succeed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else

    {

        Toast.makeText(DatabaseExampleActivity.this, "Export failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}}
```

Export CSV to XLS part

```
 public class CSVToExcelConverter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(DatabaseExampleActivity.this);

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{this.dialog.setMessage("Exporting to excel...");
 this.dialog.show();}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    ArrayList arList=null;
    ArrayList al=null;

    //File dbFile= new File(getDatabasePath("database_name").toString());
    File dbFile=getDatabasePath("database_name");
    String yes= dbFile.getAbsolutePath();

    String inFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/excerDB.csv";
    outFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/test.xls";
    String thisLine;
    int count=0;

    try {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inFilePath);
    DataInputStream myInput = new DataInputStream(fis);
    int i=0;
    arList = new ArrayList();
    while ((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null)
    {
    al = new ArrayList();
    String strar[] = thisLine.split(",");
    for(int j=0;j<strar.length;j++)
    {
    al.add(strar[j]);
    }
    arList.add(al);
    System.out.println();
    i++;
    }} catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("shit");
    }

    try
    {
    HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");
    for(int k=0;k<arList.size();k++)
    {
    ArrayList ardata = (ArrayList)arList.get(k);
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0+k);
    for(int p=0;p<ardata.size();p++)
    {
    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
    String data = ardata.get(p).toString();
    if(data.startsWith("=")){
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
    data=data.replaceAll("=", "");
    cell.setCellValue(data);
    }else if(data.startsWith("\"")){
    data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    cell.setCellValue(data);
    }else{
    data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
    cell.setCellValue(data);
    }
    //*/
    // cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outFilePath);
    hwb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated");
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    } //main method ends
    return true;
}

protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success)

{

    if (this.dialog.isShowing())

    {

        this.dialog.dismiss();

    }

    if (success)

    {

        Toast.makeText(DatabaseExampleActivity.this, "file is built!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    else

    {

        Toast.makeText(DatabaseExampleActivity.this, "file fail to build", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}


}
```

Comment: I want to directly upload from a app to google excel sheet is this possible

Comment: @Asmi this answer does not provide any information on google spreadsheets.

Comment: Yes this answer does not provide any Information any body have anyother solution please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to study about [google spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en) APIs

Comment: it do not help me can you have alternate suggestion

Comment: you will have to study on google spreadsheet apis and its android integration. to start with refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838963/android-google-spreadsheet-api) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665451/current-android-google-spreadsheet-api-example-for-writing) question.

Comment: I studied but I couldn't get any solution till yet.